# Vba unable to get correct value of a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the value of column I from the A workbook. I have closed all other workbooks but not able to get correct values. It is displaying me the term "Balancing" every time which is not present in the workbook A. I am not getting where that word is coming from.

```
Sub newapproach()
    Set ws1 = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
    Workbooks("A.xlsx").Activate
    lastRow11 = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow11 To 1 Step -1
        If i <> "" Then
            Value = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "I").Value
            MsgBox (Value)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: In the Immediate Window, type in `?Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Name` and press Enter.  What does it say?  Is it the name of the worksheet that you think you are referring to?

Comment: Or change your `MsgBox (Value)` to say `MsgBox Value & "|" & Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "I").Address(External:=True)`

Comment: Thanks, I got the Issue there is some hidden worksheet that's why not getting the correct value.

Comment: LOL - that's one of the problems you have when you use a numerical index with the `Worksheets` collection

Comment: `If i <> "" Then` You compare an integer with a string ("") which is not ok

Comment: Please specify what kind of data you have in column "I". Right now you are comparing a integer with string which is not ok as @SBF mension. Do you use Option Explicit ?

Comment: No, The value type is general.